# Getting Warning: `NaN` is an invalid value for the `width` css style property working with Pigeon Maps and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to geolocate the center of my map, but when I add variables I get this error:

`` react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: `NaN` is an invalid value for the `width` css style property ``

My code is:

```
import React from "react"
import {Map, Marker} from "pigeon-maps"
import {maptiler} from 'pigeon-maps/providers'

const maptilerProvider = maptiler('****************', 'streets')
let userLatitude;
let userLongitude;

export default function MyMap() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation not supported");
    }
    function geolocationSuccess(position) {
        userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function geolocationError() {
        console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }

    return (
        <Map
            provider={maptilerProvider}
            dprs={[1, 2]}
            height={600}
            defaultCenter={[userLatitude,userLongitude]}
            defaultZoom={8}
             >
        </Map>
    )
}
```

If I introduce numbers it works properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you may have forgotten to use the `<Marker/>` in your code. Try this one...

```js
import React from "react"
import {Map, Marker} from "pigeon-maps"
import {maptiler} from 'pigeon-maps/providers'

const maptilerProvider = maptiler('****************', 'streets')
let userLatitude;
let userLongitude;

export default function MyMap() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation not supported");
    }
    function geolocationSuccess(position) {
        userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function geolocationError() {
        console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }

    return (
        <Map
            provider={maptilerProvider}
            dprs={[1, 2]}
            height={600}
            defaultCenter={[userLatitude,userLongitude]}
            defaultZoom={8}
        >
          <Marker width={50} anchor={[50.879, 4.6997]} />
        </Map>
    )
}
```

If that even didn't work, try to progress slowly and follow the instructions on their official docs below.
https://pigeon-maps.js.org/docs/installation